# Differences between `useRef` and ref variable in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

I have this

```
const CompA = () => {
  let _input;
  return (
    <input ref={el => _input = el} type="text" />
  );
}
```

And this

```
const CompB = () => {
  const _input = useRef(null);
  return (
    <input ref={_input} type="text" />
  );
}
```

Two `_input` is the ref object of the `input` tag and I can't find the differences between them.

My question is: What are the differences between two `_input` and which `_input` is better?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two ways of defining, refs are not equivalent.

Consider the first example

```
const CompA = () => {
  let _input;
  return (
    <input ref={el => _input = el} type="text" />
  );
}
```

In this example, whenever, CompA re-renders, as new variable `_input` is created and for instance if you have a useEffect in CompA which is meant to run on initial render and it executes something at an interval using this ref variable it would lead to inconsitencies.

Now consider second case

```
const CompA = () => {
  const _input = useRef(null);
  return (
    <input ref={_input} type="text" />
  );
}
```

In this case, even though the _input variable is created on each render, `useRef` ensures that it receives the same reference that it receives the first time and not initialise it again. `useRef` is the right way to define refs for `functional Components`. For class components you can use `createRef` or the callback pattern you mention

Comment: This is especially applicable when the value is used in a dependency array of a `useEffect()` hook. Using a variable instead of a ref can cause unintended extra triggerings of the `useEffect()` hook in question.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

> This works because useRef() creates a plain JavaScript object. The only difference between useRef() and creating a {current: ...} object yourself is that useRef will give you the same ref object on every render.

In other words, `useRef` will keep the reference on every render/update, by changing props or state. On the other side, simple `ref` as variable will be erased at every component cycle.

Comment: This means that `const ref = useRef(1)` is equal to `const ref = useMemo(() => ({ 
current: 1 }), [])`